# Infinite While Loop Stopping

Tags: c, kernel-module

I have an infinite while loop and somehow it stops.

*code:*

```
struct task_struct *thread;

static int __ubut thread_init(void)
{
  thread = thread_run(kernel_thread_function, NULL, "my_thread");
  return 0;
}

int kernel_thread_function(void *t)
{
   while(1)
      printk("hello world");

   return 0;
}

static void __exit thread_exit(void)
{
   kthread_stop(thread);
}
```

---

output:

> hello world ... hello world
>
> *** sudden stop ***

The thread gets created correctly inside `innit.` If I run my while loop with a counter it will run until the counter is done, but if I run it `while(1)` it dies fairly quickly. I guess the kernel is killing my loop, but my thread stays active when I run the command `ps` and I see all processes that are still running.

I tried using `msleep_interruptible(2000);` like another post on SO suggested but it didn't fix my problem.

So how do I make the kernel not stop my infinite loop? And yes it has to run for ever.

Comment: while(1) is definitely not the problem. You have a bug in your code.

Comment: What if I told you that I commented out all my code and left `printk();` inside my while loop and still it stopped. Have you ever tried to do an infinite loop in the kernel?

Comment: Reproduce the problem with a minimal test example, and show it.

Comment: My code above prints about 100 times. With only printk inside the loop, there is no more code except for the innit running the thread and that is trivial stuff. I would show you the output but it is just printks, the important thing about it is that it stops when it should not.

Comment: I am using `insmod` to load my kernel module.

Comment: How do you know it "dies"? What's your method for observing the printk output? Have you confirmed that there are no printk rate limiting messages in the log?

Comment: Trust me, it stops. There is no rate limiting message. If anybody doesn't believe me just run code above as a kernel module.

Comment: Try putting a sleep(10) before the printk, and see how many messages, if any, it prints. Could tell you if it's a threading issue or something to do with the printing.

Comment: What is the OS?  Linux?  Can you post uname -a?

Comment: Does `dmesg` tell you anything else?  Or does it just show that you're kernel thread died?

Comment: What is `__ubut`? Is that supposed to be `__init`?

Comment: I do think that the title `Infinite While Loop Stopping` has a certain poetic quality.